# Question 4g from Miscellaneous Exercises 2 from F. Mary Hart - Guide To Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

The question asks you to find the limit of the following sequence $(a_n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. 
 $a_n = n(\sqrt{n^2+144}-\sqrt{n^2-1})$.

My thoughts were that as n grows $\sqrt{n^2+144}-\sqrt{n^2-1}$ tends to $0$. This is where I got stuck as the n on the outside grows larger. The hints told me that you can do this by using the Algebra of Limits and also the answer is $\frac{145}{2}$.

Comment: **Hint**: $\sqrt a-\sqrt b=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}.$

Comment: If I let $a = n^2+144$ and $b = n^2-1$. Then I would get $n\frac{145}{\sqrt[]{n^2+144}+\sqrt[]{n^2-1}}$. Thanks it makes sense.

Comment: Sorry I just edited it, I realised my mistake.

Comment: Happy doing math!